# Crocodile Logia Defense Explanation

Tags: one-piece

Crocodile explained that he has trained his Logia to the point he can activate his sand defense off of reflex. Can anyone tell me what chapter/sbs this is? I don't remember and I need it for a video.

Answer (score 4):

Check:

```
Episode 110: "Merciless Fight to the Death! Luffy vs. Crocodile"
```

Reference: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_178

> However, as Crocodile continues to try to explain to Luffy why he will never win, Luffy cuts him off by clocking his face with a haymaker, that although doing no physical damage, shuts Crocodile up and enrages him. Before the three minutes are up, Crocodile decides he is done playing with Luffy, even though Luffy says to have been fighting seriously the whole time. He then shows off his first impressive attack- Desert Spada (Desert Sword in italian). It sends a blade of sand towards Luffy that he once again narrowly dodges. Crocodile compliments Luffy on his nice reflexes, and claims that had it hit him, he would have certainly died. Crocodile finally explains to Luffy why he will never win - unlike Luffy, **Crocodile trained his Devil Fruit powers to the point of mastering them. He claims that any Devil fruit power can be powerful in a fight as along as someone knows how to use them properly.** Crocodile says to Luffy that if he has proper training, even his his skills can be as formidable as any - but claims that Luffy's not there, just like all the other fools who waste time obsessing over their abilities Crocodile attacks again instantly afterwards with Desert Girasole (Desert Sunflower), creating a large pit of quicksand that Luffy just happened to be standing in. He escapes however with another bazooka.

```
Chapter 178 page 5 of manga
```

[image]

Comment: nah, the scene i'm looking for is where he specifically talks about logias reacting. i believe he says something about how logia users train themselves to react to attacks reflexivvely

Comment: Did you read the paragraph above? its almost the same as what you are looking for. Croc said there "if he has proper training, even his his skills can be as formidable as any". But if that's not it. I can't think of any part that he says that. hmm.